# Initialize a long in Java

Tags: java, long-integer

[Primitive Data Types - oracle doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) says the range of **`long`** in Java is `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.
But when I do something like this in my eclipse

```
long i = 12345678910;
```

it shows me "`The literal 12345678910 of type int is out of range`" error.

**There are 2 questions.**

1) How do I initialize the **`long`** with the value `12345678910`?

2) Are all numeric literals by default of type **`int`**?

Comment: And how about initializing a Long?

Comment: @WolfgangFahl Same rules for `Long` - due to auto-boxing, you can use `Long i = 12345678910L`, or use `Long i = Long.valueOf(12345678910L)` for those cases where you cannot use auto-boxing.

Answer (score 479, accepted):

1. You should add `L`: `long i = 12345678910L;`.
2. Yes.

BTW: it doesn't have to be an upper case L, but lower case is confused with `1` many times :).

Comment: Just in case someone was wondering: the same goes for hex, e.g. `0x200000000L`

Comment: @Victor Long.valueOf(long) returns a Long, not a primitive long. MByD's solution avoids to rely on auto-boxing.

Comment: @user149408 Perhaps you mean `0x20000000L`?

Comment: @Pluto `0x20000000L` would work but can still be represented by `int` (a 32-bit integer), thus `0x20000000` would work just as well. `0x200000000L` breaks that boundary, making the trailing `L` necessary.

Answer (score 72):

1. You need to add the `L` character to the end of the number to make Java recognize it as a long.

   ```
   long i = 12345678910L;
   ```
2. Yes.

See [Primitive Data Types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) which says "An integer literal is of type long if it ends with the letter L or l; otherwise it is of type int."

Answer (score 43):

You need to add uppercase `L` at the end like so

```
long i = 12345678910L;
```

Same goes true for float with `3.0f`

Which should answer both of your questions

Answer (score 20):

To initialize long you need to append "L" to the end. 
It can be either uppercase or lowercase.

All the numeric values are by default `int`. Even when you do any operation of `byte` with any integer, `byte` is first promoted to `int` and then any operations are performed.

Try this

```
byte a = 1; // declare a byte
a = a*2; //  you will get error here
```

You get error because `2` is by default `int`. 
Hence you are trying to multiply `byte` with `int`.
Hence result gets typecasted to `int` which can't be assigned back to `byte`.