# Java long to binary

Tags: java

something I thought was simple ends up not so much.

I need to convert a long number to binary.

For example:

```
String b =  Integer.toBinaryString(1028);
```

the output is 10000000100

but when I use  Integer.toBinaryString(2199023255552); it does not work. Of course the number is too big for this function and I can't find one that does convert from long.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Add an `L` to indicate its a long<1> and use the [Long class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toBinaryString%28long%29)<2>:

```
Long.toBinaryString(2199023255552L);
```

<1> Constants in java are considered `int`s unless you specify otherwise.

<2> `Integer.toBinaryString()` receives an int as parameter, not long.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry, I first did not see the L. Kind of strange but ok....

Comment: I am curious, I always have to use the L at the end? I was looking at all the samples I found online and none have that.

Comment: When you want to specify a `long`, then yes.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad - Your comment seemed familiar to me :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834037/initialize-a-long-in-java/6834049#6834049

Comment: @MByD lol what a Coincidence. I remember I said that for someone but never expected it's for same person and similar answer. wow!