# How to convert big int number to Binary ? - Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert int to binary and i am doing below code.

```
public static String intToBinary16Bit(String strInt) {
        String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(strInt);
        return String.format("%016d", Integer.parseInt(bin));
    }
```

So, if i am giving `strInt = 0211` than it is working fine and giving the output
`0000001000010001`.

But, if i am giving `strInt = 4527` than it is throwing `NumberFormateException`.

How can I resolved this issue ?

Comment: Your code cannot compile. `Integer.toBinaryString()` expects an int as an argument, not a String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [what eznme suggests here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203974/converting-decimal-to-binary-in-java/5204040#5204040):

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println(a);

        int bit=1;
        for(int i=0; i<32; i++) {
            System.out.print("  "+(((a&bit)==0)?0:1));
            bit*=2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following method, it uses recursion for conversion.

```
  private static void toBinary(int number) {
        int remainder;

        if (number <= 1) {
            System.out.print(number);
            return;
        }

        remainder = number % 2; 
        toBinary(number >> 1);
        System.out.println(remainder);
    }
```

Comment: It is working, but it is showing only in 12 bit. can you please tell me how can i formate it in 16 bit?

Comment: just check the length of the `remainder` and prepend `0` in the string. thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You try:

```
Long.toBinaryString(2199023255552L);
```

[Java long to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970084/java-long-to-binary)