# How to manipulate the bits in a long?

Tags: java, bit, long-integer

I want to transform a long to binary code, then change some bits and get the long again. I have found this post [Java long to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970084/java-long-to-binary) but I still can't achieve what I want.

I think there is two ways to achieve my goal:

1. Going from long to bitset and to long again
2. Going from long to binary String and then to int array and then to long again

```
 public static long changeHalf(long x){
        int[] firstHalf = new int[32];
        int[] secondHalf = new int[32];
        int[] result = new int[64];


        String binaryOfLong = Long.toBinaryString(x);
        for (int i = 0; i < firstHalf.length; i++) {

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < secondHalf.length; i++) {
            result[i] = secondHalf[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < firstHalf.length; i++) {
            result[i+32] = firstHalf[i];
        }

        String s = Arrays.toString(result);
        return Long.parseLong(s);
    }
```

Comment: `long` **are** binary. What do you mean by "change some bits"?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I want to swap the first 32 bits with the last 32 bits

Comment: May I ask what you think `new int[32]` and `new int[64]`do?

Comment: @Yunnosch create a Integer Array of 32 and 64 cells

Comment: OK. I was worried that you try to use it to make 32bit and 64bit variables.

Comment: @J.erome - You've said "swap" but that's not what your code appears to do...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think in the two loops on `firstHalf/secondHalf` I do the swap

Comment: @J.erome - Sorry, misread the code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than converting a `long` to arrays of `int`, just use bitwise operations.

> I want to swap the first 32 bits with the last 32 bits

That would be:

```
long result = ((x & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000l) >> 32) | ((x & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFl) << 32);
```

That masks off the first 32 bits, shifts them to the right, masks off the last 32 bits, shifts them to the left, and combines the result with `|` (OR).

[Live example](https://ideone.com/Ec99JJ):

```
class Example
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        long x = 0x1000000020000000l;
        long result = ((x & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000l) >> 32) | ((x & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFl) << 32);
        System.out.printf("0x%016X\n", x);
        System.out.printf("0x%016X\n", result);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
0x1000000020000000
0x2000000010000000
```

More in the [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Comment: Yes I have seen it right after, but I still have a question. If I give 12L, the result after the swap should be a big number like >1024 right ? But I still get 12 in return