# How to create a long value with all bits = 1

Tags: java

I tried the following:

```
public static final long DEVICE_ID_UNKNOWN = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
```

but it causes

```
The literal 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF of type int is out of range
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initialize a long in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834037/initialize-a-long-in-java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFl` and be fine.
Another way would be to use simply `-1` because this value also has all bits set. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement for details.

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify the type of the number if it can not be represented as an int. A long is a L or l (lowercase). I prefer uppercase as lowercase is easy to mistake for 1 (one).

```
public static final long DEVICE_ID_UNKNOWN = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL;
```

Or, you can just set the value to -1, but that might not be as clear in communicating the meaning "all bits 1".

Comment: +1 imho best answer (extra pluses: upper case L over lower case l; hex notation over `-1` in this case)

Answer (score 7):

You may use either of the following:

```
public static final long DEVICE_ID_UNKNOWN = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL;
```

or

```
public static final long DEVICE_ID_UNKNOWN = ~0L;
```

or

```
public static final long DEVICE_ID_UNKNOWN = -1L;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way to get all 1s

```
public static final long DEVICE_ID_UNKNOWN = ~0L;
```

Comment: `~0` means make every bit a 1 (the opposite of 0) whereas -1 happens to be all 1s as a `long` (but not as a `double`)

Comment: Can you explain? I didn't understand what you mean by 'all 1s as a long (but not as a double)'.

Comment: a double has a different bit format than a long - see IEEE 754: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: I believe this is the easiest alternative to understand. And you don't need to triple-check the number of Fs either.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static final long DEVICE_ID_UNKNOWN = -1L;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `public static final long DEVICE_ID_UNKNOWN = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL;` instead to signify that it's a long value, not an int value.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm not the `java` guy, but wouldn't `-1` do?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final long DEVICE_ID_UNKNOWN = 0xFFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFFL;
```

Usefull reference http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: +1 Thanks for useful answer but `_` is only in Java SE 7 and later so I will avoid it.