# Does Java bitwise representation of long vary?

Tags: java, arrays, bit-manipulation, long-integer, fill

I would like to fill a Java array of longs, so that all of its bits are set to 1.  I've found out that the [corresponding long value is -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573762/how-to-create-a-long-value-with-all-bits-1/8573797#8573797), or "0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFl":

```
long l = -1L;
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(l));

"1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
```

So I use `Arrays.fill()` to fill the array with 1's:

```
final long allBitsOn = -1L;
long[] bits = new long[arrayLength];
Arrays.fill(bits, allBitsOn);
```

This array is a fundamental infrastructure of a major project, and I want to be completely sure that long has 64 bits, and that `long(-1)` will always have all its bits set to 1, across all VM implementations and future versions of Java.

Is this assumption safe?

Comment: Don't know if you accidently missed it, but the so post from which you found out how to set a long specifies that it has to be : `long l = -1L;`. The L is there for a [reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769963/javas-l-number-long-specification-question). Cheers

Comment: @Daneo: `long l = -1;` and `long l =-1L;` produce **exactly** the same bytecode (http://pastie.org/5441210). There certainly *can* be times when you need the `L`, but not when you're assigning a literal `-1` to a `long`. Not to say it's not good practice.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the clarification, and to confirm. It might not be necessary now, but just to prevent cases like [this](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/165728/why-long-variable-is-taking-integer-value) by not applying that practice. As that link says not applying the L makes it autoconvert, and that will work in the case the value fits the size of an int. I thought it'd be better not to rely on such.

Comment: @Daneo: Agreed, always best to write it out.

Comment: Updated my answer - always good to be explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the assumption is safe. From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2):

> 4.2. Primitive Types and Values
>
> The integral types are `byte`, `short`, `int`, and **`long`**, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and **64-bit signed two's-complement integers**, respectively, and char, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units (§3.1).

In [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), `-1` is represented by the bit pattern consisting of all ones.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this assumption safe?

Yes, it's defined by the Java Language Specification, [Section 4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2):

> The integral types are `byte`, `short`, `int`, and `long`, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively...

What you describe is how [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) integer numbers work, -1 is "all bits on".