# Range of primitive type long in Java

Tags: java

I have found in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Long.html) that range of long is from -2^63 to 2^63-1.

When I run this for cycle I'm unable to get over cca 2 000 000 000.

```
Log.d(TAG, "Long MAX = " + Long.MAX_VALUE);
for (int i = 1; i < 45; i++) {
    long result = i * 184528125;
    Log.d(TAG, "" + result);
}
```

Output is "Long MAX = 9223372036854775807" and result values in graph is below.

[image: graph of previous for cycle]

Sample Java project on codingground.com is [here](http://goo.gl/2GF8SW).

What am I missing?

Comment: An `int * int` is an `int`.  It doesn't "know" you are going to assign it to a `long` or a `double`.

Comment: Of course it would make more sense IMHO if an `int * int` was a `long` but that is another story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
long result = i * 184528125;
```

It multiplies two 32-bit `int` values. The result will be a 32-bit `int` (which has overflowed) which is then converted to a 64-bit `long`.

You want to do 64-bit multiplication instead. Make one of the two operands a `long`. The easiest way to do that is to use the `L` suffix on the constant:

```
long result = i * 184528125L;
```

Comment: Thank you Jesper. I knew that there is some really basic problem. Sometimes you have to close your eyes and count to ten. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're doing *`int`* math here:

```
long result = i * 184528125;
```

...because `i` is an `int`, and numeric literals are `int`s by default. So first `i * 184528125` happens, limited to the `int` range, and then the result (which wraps, as you found) is promoted to `long` and assigned to `result`.

Instead, either make `i` a `long` or make the numeric literal a long:

```
long result = i * 184528125L;
// Note -------------------^
```

Now the multiplication happens with `long` values, with access to the full `long` range.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
long result = i * 184528125;
```

The right hand side is evaluated in 32-bit integer arithmetic, because both operands are `int`. There's *then* an implicit conversion to `long`. To fix it, just make the RHS a `long` constant:

```
long result = i * 184528125L;
```

Note that this is similar to the common problem of doing something like:

```
int x = 1;
double d = x / 2; // d is 0, not 0.5...
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Use a [`long` literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834037/initialize-a-long-in-java) by appending an `L` to the end of digits:

```
long result = i * 184528125L;
```

**Solution 2:**

Change the for loop to:

```
for (long i = 0; i<45; i++){
```

This will make sure you have at least one `long` value when doing this calculation:

```
long result = i * 184528125;//i is now a long
```

**Solution 3:**

Cast one of the values as a `long`:

```
long result = i * (long)184528125;
```

Answer (score 1):

`long result = i * 184528125;`

The statement above is the culprit. By default, numerical values are `int`. Also you defined `i` as an `int` as well.

options:

1. Define `i` as `long`
2. Add `long` modifier `L` to the `184528125`

Answer (score 0):

2<sup>63</sup> is not divisible by 184528125. The nearest number you can get with your method is 49983556906 * 184528125 = 9223372036694981250.

If you Log.d("" + 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL), you will get 2<sup>63</sup>-1

Comment: Has nothing to do with the question: *"I'm unable to get over cca 2 000 000 000"*