# Java division returns incorrect result

Tags: java

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        final long a= 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
        final long b= 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

        System.out.println(a/b);
 }
```

It should return 1000, but returns 5 why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` is `86400000`. If you multiply it by `1000`, it will overflow the `int` type (because the maximum value that an `int` can hold is `2147483647` which is a lot less than `86400000000`)  and you will get `500654080` for `a`.

Then, when you divide the result by `86400000`, you will get `5`.

In order to fix this, you need to explicitly specify that the result from the multiplication will be `long` - this is because all the numeric operators in Java produce integers, unless explicitly instructed to produce some other numeric type.

Just appending a `L` on some of the operands will be sufficient:

```
final long a = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000L;
```

Comment: It's better to use `L` in all literals... Just in case it overflows before reaching the last one...

Comment: @Codebender  24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 will never overflow.

Comment: In that case it will still overflow if the expression was say `24000 * 60 * 60 *  1000 * 1000L`... Because the first 4 literals will be multiplied as int. Or make the first one long... Not the last...

Answer (score 1):

Plain number in java considered as `int`.  You need to append L to convert to `long`. Without `L` `a =500654080`, which is wrong.

```
 final long a= 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000L;// Append L
```

Answer (score 1):

`24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000` this cause numeric overflow since it will consider as an `int` value. So you will get odd result. You should use `long` here.

You should use `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000L` (This is how you define `long`)

[How to initialize long in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834037/initialize-a-long-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with above answers You can achieve what you want in below two ways:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //way 1
        final long a =(long) 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
        final long b = (long)24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        System.out.println(a / b);
        //way 2
        final long a1 = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000L;
        final long b1 = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L;
        System.out.println(a1 / b1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BigInteger or Long:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final BigInteger a = new BigInteger("24");
        //multiply by creating big integers....
        final BigInteger b = new BigInteger("60")

        System.out.println(a.divide(b));
 }
```