# the literal x of type int is out of range

Tags: java

The method is the following:

```
public static long repeatedString(String s, long n) {
    
    
    int convertedLong = (int) n;
    String repeated = new String(new char[convertedLong]).replace("\0", s);
    System.out.println(repeated);

    long numberOfAs = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < convertedLong; i++ )
    {
        if (repeated.charAt(i) == 'a')
        {
            numberOfAs += 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(numberOfAs);
    return numberOfAs;
}
```

method works fine when the parameter `n` is small, however when it is large like `1000000000000` it throws an exception:

```
The literal 1000000000000 of type int is out of range
```

Comment: The biggest int is 2147483647.

Comment: Yes, you have to use `long` instead of int when using too high numbers

Comment: [`java.math.BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) may be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The int type in Java can be used to represent any whole number from -2147483648 to 2147483647.
It seems you've reach the limitation of what the int type can hold. Consider using long. As the method you are using takes a long.

From:

```
int convertedLong = (int) n;
```

To:

```
long convertedLong = n;
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is coming because your convertedLong is of type int. Why?

Make it long and also variable `i` to be long.

This error is coming because you are calling the function by just `1000000000`.

Append `L` to it, to pass it as "long" like

```
100000000000L
```

else it will take as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

All number literals in java, unless otherwise specified, are typed as an `int`. So what you'll need to do is define your literal as a `long` by adding the `L` suffix to the literal.

`1000000000000L`

Also why are you casting your `long` to an `int`? that seesm to defeat the purpose?

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834037/initialize-a-long-in-java) question for more info

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the method with the following parameters `repeatedString("anyText",1000000000000)` right? This would not even compile you have to extend a `L` at the end of your number to give the compiler the information that this is a `long` and not an `int`, so at first you call your function like this: `repeatedString("anyText",1000000000000L)` but if you think about it it's useless because you casting it to an `int` which then removes all the bytes which the `int` is not able to hold. So stop converting the `long` to an `int` and just use the given parameter as `long`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static long repeatString(String s, long n) {
    int length = s.length();
    long mod = n % length;
    long count = 0, rest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == 'a') {
            ++count;
            if (i < mod)
                ++rest;
        }
    }
    return count * (n / length) + rest;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "aabca";
    for (long i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        System.out.println(i + " : " + repeatString(s, i));
    long x = 1000000000000L;
    System.out.println(x + " : " + repeatString(s, x));
}
```

output:

```
0 : 0
1 : 1
2 : 2
3 : 2
4 : 2
5 : 3
6 : 4
7 : 5
8 : 5
9 : 5
1000000000000 : 600000000000
```